# Why does my Ethernet interface not get assigned an IP address by the DHCP server?

Tags: networking, ethernet, interface

My machine has 1 built-in Ethernet port and I also plugged in a USB-Ethernet adapter. It looks like Linux correctly identified the new device, but it has no IP address.

Here is the output from `ifconfig`:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.203.47  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.203.255
        inet6 fe80::a5d:1df2:bcb0:eb9e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:5f:01:df:77:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14340  bytes 2287405 (2.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10415  bytes 6577080 (6.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f8:e4:3b:9f:e7:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1033  bytes 112633 (109.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1033  bytes 112633 (109.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is the output from `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:df:77:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.203.47/24 brd 192.168.203.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 8638252sec preferred_lft 7558252sec
    inet6 fe80::a5d:1df2:bcb0:eb9e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:df:77:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:e4:3b:9f:e7:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Here is the output from `route`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.203.1   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.203.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

What do I need to do to enable `eth1`?

#### EDIT

I tried unplugging the connection to the built-in interface (`eth0`) and only plugging in the cable for `eth1`. This caused me to get an IP address for that interface, and now both interfaces have IP addresses. The question still remains though, how can I force this behavior without unplugging the cables?

#### UPDATE

When I plug everything in *before boot* then I get both interfaces working. So it seems there is something in the boot sequence that also handles the adapter correctly. The only time it seems to not work is when I plug the adapter in while the other interface is already connected and working.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: This is on custom Raspbian built with pi-gen. My mistake, I thought it was Ubuntu but it's plain Debian. I should have posted this to unix.stackexchange.com instead... should I move the question? Or maybe it can still be answered here. I don't know if this is specific to Ubuntu or not.

Comment: It should be posted on [unix.se] and this will be closed - sorry. 

Comment: Ok, I moved the question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/721657/384822